# Discord bot Ignoring exception in on_connect

Tags: discord.py

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    for file in os.listdir('./cogs'):
        if file.endswith('.py'):
            bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{file[:-3]}')

    bot.run(bot.token)
```

**Output**

```
Ignoring exception in on_connect
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", 
**line 377, in _run_event**
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\bot.py", 
**line 1164, in on_connect**
    await self.sync_commands()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\bot.py", 
**line 738, in sync_commands**
    app_cmds = await self.register_commands(
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\bot.py", 
**line 531, in register_commands**
    prefetched_commands = await self._bot.http.get_guild_commands(
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 360, in request
    raise Forbidden(response, data)
**discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50001): Missing Access**
```

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Boss\discord-bot\bot3\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 2, in <module>
    for file in os.listdir('./cogs'):
`                                                                                                                                          **NameError: name 'os' is not defined**

Answer (score 0):

Your bot needs to be invited with the `applications.commands` scope to sync commands in the command tree to the guild.

[discord.py FAQ](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#application-commands):

> Bots need to be invited with the `applications.commands` scope in addition to the bot scope. For example, invite the bot with the following URL: `https://discord.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=<client id>&scope=applications.commands+bot`

Comment: I had invite bot to my server but it seem it can't use the slash command except it show w only buit-in command